nvidia-driver 560 is the "only" nvidia choice, does not work well, how to install another version?
560 is dysfunctional, "app centre" firmware updater" and other Ubuntu components things to render window content.
The "additional drivers" window uses over one minute to populate since Ubuntu 24.10
If I try to install 535, 550,. .. I am forced/tricked into to installing 560.

The card is a "4070 Ti Super"
Is this why I can only use v560?    - are there any fixes for the inop applications/windows ?

Three sec. to populate the additional drivers on my 3080/Wayland/560-open, no problems noted on your mentioned apps. Does dmesg have any errors? which driver does lshw -c video say is running on your nvidia hardware? How did you install the Nvidia 560 driver?  Maybe purge (not just remove) every package with nvidia in its name, and reinstall (I use the graphics-drivers ppa to get 560. ubuntu-drivers install should then grab it, but maybe specify to get the -open, I forgot.

App centre says: "Unable to create GL content" no message in journalct
"Dec 03 22:08:15 loke snap-store[42301]: Failed to uninitialize GLArea: Unable to create a GL context
Dec 03 22:08:15 loke snap-store[42301]: Attempted to set message handler on an FlBinaryMessenger without an engine
Dec 03 22:08:15 loke snap-store[42301]: Attempted to set message handler on an FlBinaryMessenger without an engine
"

I did install noveau and did "sudo apt remove --purge '^nvidia.'
"  -  as well as
sudo rm -rf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf
sudo rm -rf /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf
sudo rm -rf /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia
sudo rm -rf /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia*
sudo rm -rf ~/.nv
Before reinstalling 560.
As for the delay;  "ubuntu-drivers devices
" is also delayed, I see no clues in dmesg or journalctl for that.
So right now, I am running the 560 driver, also confirmed by the Nvidia tool.

Quite a list, but there are about a dozen packages with nvidia in the name that do not start with nvidia (libnvidia...etc.) and one (screen-resolution-extra) that mentions nvidia in its description.  Purge them all before the reinstall -- start clean. Note a Wayland bug 2042301 about slow  display of windows contents, not present under xorg just after login.
